# Can't resolve 'encoding' issue in terminal

Tags: next.js

Hi so I am trying to send a message to my ai character and everytime i send a message i get this error in terminal.

```
 warn ./node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'encoding' in 'C:\Users\ctcco\chat-sage\node_modules\node-fetch\lib'

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js
./node_modules/cross-fetch/dist/node-ponyfill.js
./node_modules/cross-fetch/dist/node-polyfill.js
./node_modules/@pinecone-database/pinecone/dist/index.js
./lib/memory.ts
./app/api/chat/[chatId]/route.ts
```

I dont know what this means or how to fix it, if you need to see some of my files i would be happy to share them

I was having issues with readLatestHistory issues with my characters but I fixed this and began to test and now I have this issue

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar warning when I tried to implement a chatbot for my **Next.js** application.

- One way around it, though not the best approach for production, is to
  install the encoding package like this if you are using npm:

  `npm i encoding`
- Better approach is to verify that all your api calls are made from
  the Server components if you are using **NextJS**.
- Additionally you can edit you `next.config.js` file to filter for these type of warning like this:

  webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
  if (!isServer) {
  config.resolve.fallback = {
  ...config.resolve.fallback, // if you already have some fallbacks defined
  encoding: false,
  };
  }
  return config;
  },